# Can't show Google Charts in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

So here is what I've done so far:

1) Installed **angular-google-charts** through `bower install`
2) Create a controller with this header:

```
angular.module("sbAdminApp", ["googlechart", "googlechart-docs"])
.controller("GenericChartCtrl",['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope) {
```

3) Add this script to the index:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/src/googleChart.js"></script>
```

and

```
 <div ng-app="sbAdminApp">

        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>
```

4) To finally show the Chart, I call:

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12" ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="chartObject" class="chart-container"> </div>
    </div>
```

5) In App.js. I declare this:

```
    .state('dashboard.table', {
        templateUrl: 'views/table.html',
        url: '/table', 
    controller: "GenericChartCtrl",
      resolve: {
            loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'googlechart',
                        files: [
        'bower_components/angular-google-chart/dist/ng-google-chart.min.js'
      ]
                    }),
                    $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'sbAdminApp',
                        files: ['scripts/controllers/GoogleChartContoller.js']
                    })
            }
        }

    })
```

Am I missing something? For some reason, I can't access to **localhost:9000/#/dashboard/table**, it just doesn't load.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is wht the web console shows:
[image]

Comment: Hi Miguel,Please open your browser console and check if any error is logged.If so,please post it here.

Comment: @Raghu I edited the question with an image with the errors. Click on it to see it bigger. Thanks!

Comment: You have not loaded your dependencies properly.Please refer to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod). Try reproducing the same scenario in a plunkr or jsfiddle.So that we can help you better.

Comment: @Raghu Where can I check if I loaded the dependencies? Everything looks OK, but I cant get it running...

Comment: Where have you added this line `<script src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/src/googleChart.js"></script>`?Is it before loading angular js or after?Try placing it first in your scripts.
And also can you first try loading the `ng-google-chart.min.js` by including it in scripts tag instead of lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are getting [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) since the referenced [`googleChart.js` file](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/blob/development/src/googleChart.js) does not contain module implementation.

Replace the line:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/src/googleChart.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
```